# Amazon S3 caching does not work even if I have set metadata cache control to several days

Tags: caching, amazon-s3, browser-cache, cache-control

I need to cache images that are hosted on Amazon S3 but there is no way to do it.
I have set the "metadata" cache control on Amazon S3 and also added the cache control in my .htaccess file.
No way to make it works.

The website is streetstylejournal.com (under dev) and I'm trying to improve the page load speed for mobile.

This one of the images that has expiration set on S3

https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/streetstylejournal/homepage/london-fashion-week-ss19-street-style.jpg

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your header value is incorrect, so it would have no effect.

```
Cache-Control: 1728000
```

This should be...

```
Cache-Control: max-age=1728000
```

Also note that S3 completely ignores `.htaccess` files.

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control.

Comment: Hi Michael, thank you for your answer. I have added the tag <meta http-equiv="Cache-control"  max-age="1209600" content="public">

Comment: That shouldn't be necessary if you correct the cache-control settings on the objects in the bucket.